# Transaction knockout

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

Knockout (KO) bindings update the view-model immediately. This is not so great for edit dialogs; I'd like to set up commit and rollback behaviour on OK and Cancel buttons.

I can think of several ways to go about this but it's highly unlikely that I'm the first to face this particular problem, so what's the conventional solution?

You can't just do this

```
$.extend(buffer, this);
app.showDialog(buffer).then(function () {
  //if ok clicked then $.extend(this, buffer);
});
```

because copied observable fields refer to the *same* observable instances, it's a shallow copy. You'd have to convert to literals member by member.

Comment: can you make sample fiddle for this?

Comment: I suppose I could work something up; the problem isn't specific to the context in which I've encountered it so I guess I can probably hack around one of the KO samples.

Comment: Highly related: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Comment: @nemesv - that is so close to the (working) solution that I came up with that if you offer it as an answer you get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the plugin you're looking for:

https://github.com/romanych/ko.editables

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. He even calls the methods commit and rollback!